# datepicker js with rails strange thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

i'm developing my app and i want to show datepicker js in a field inside my form but i have a little problem, i hope anyone can help me.

My app uses modal bootstrap to load all the forms, f.e. when i click the button "New Task" a modal appears with the form to add a new task, so, in that form i have a text field for :date that i want to complete with datepicker js. The problem is that the datepicker never appears BUT if i run the code in my .js in the console datepicker appears normally.

I added jquery-ui-rails and in the application.js and application.css the requires. Here is my code.

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .
```

Application.css

```
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require sb-admin
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree
```

I have a file custom_script.js in app/assets/javascripts with these code

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

and my _form.html.haml:

```
=form_for([@list, @list.tasks.build]) do |t|
=t.label :name, class: 'control-label'
  =t.text_field :name

  =t.label :date,  "Expiration Date", {class: 'control-label'}
  =t.text_field :date, {:class => "datepicker", "readonly" => "readonly"}

  =t.label :active, class: "checkbox inline" do
    =t.check_box :active
    %span Active?

  =t.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

So, the problem is that when i click that text_field the datepicker does not appear BUT if I run the code inside custom_script.js in the console the datepicker appears normally.

I've tried with page:load because i use turbolinks but it didn't work, so, I really don't know what i'm doing wrong.

The form is loaded by ajax call because the button "New Task" has remote: true, so, i think that is the problem, but i dont know how to solve it.

I hope you can help me people!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening. After you load the page, the code `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` is called. When you introduce the modal, this code does not run again. Try adding

```
javascript:
 $(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker();
 });
```

to the bottom of your `my _form.html.haml`. This way, after that file is loaded the JS will run.

or to keep it consistent with what you already have, use the `on` method in your js file...

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('load','.datepicker',function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
   });
 });
```

What this does is that for now and forever it will attach the datepicker to `.datepicker`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your java script code has already been run before your forms load.

What you have to do call datepicker method, in your my_form.html.hmal
Like following code.

```
=form_for([@list, @list.tasks.build]) do |t|
  =t.label :name, class: 'control-label'
  =t.text_field :name

  =t.label :date,  "Expiration Date", {class: 'control-label'}
  =t.text_field :date, {:class => "datepicker", "readonly" => "readonly"}

  =t.label :active, class: "checkbox inline" do
    =t.check_box :active
    %span Active?

 =t.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'

:javascript  
  $(document).ready(function($) {  
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
```

Hope, it will work fine.

Comment: Haml::SyntaxError in Tasks#new

Showing /home/santi/activities-list-RoR/app/views/tasks/_form.html.haml where line #15 raised:
Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/shared/_content_box.html.haml, app/views/tasks/_new_box.html.haml, app/views/tasks/new.js.haml

Comment: There was some syntax error in javascript tag, I have updated and it works fine at my side.